# Python 3.5 Numbers to symbols

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to convert numbers from a list to symbols
This is the code I have so far (not exact same but the same gist)

```
if num1 = 4:
    count[1] = count[1] + 4

count[0,4,2,7,6,5,9]
print(count[1])
```

output: 4

My desired output if count[1] = 4 is:

$$$$

if count[1] = 10:

$$$$$$$$$$

You get the point, I am just struggling and it's for uni so guidance is preferred rather than the answer.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you'd prefer guidance, I won't modify your code, but:

```
>>> "A" * 5
'AAAAA'
>>> "$" * 10
'$$$$$$$$$$'
```

You can multiply a string by a number to repeat the string that many times.

This means that `"$" * count[1]` would produce your desired number of dollar signs.

Comment: Be careful when "multiplying" lists. If not properly done it will create several references to the same list instead of several different lists. `li = [ [ ] ] * 2 ;
li[0].append(1)` won't output what you might expect.

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh, I've never noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate a char or list of chars by multiplying it with the number you want to repeat.

```
>>> def count(lis):
    if len(lis) > 1:
        return '$'*lis[1]


>>> count([0, 4, 5])
'$$$$'
>>> count([0, 1])
'$'
>>>
```